# My virtual environment is showing 2 python paths

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I've been using the virtualenvwrapper for windows(10) for some time. I'm running Python 3.6.1 on my machine and recently tried upgrading to 3.6.5 and had some issues (won't go into that here!) and reverted back to 3.6.1

Since then, when I create a virtual environment, I get 2 paths to Python: the system one and the within the environment, something like:

```
where python (run when I am within the created environment)
-> C:\Users\.....\Envs\sampleenv\Scripts\python.exe
-> C:\Users\.....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
```

This is causing some issues when I run code. I'm not sure how to fix this - any help much appreciated.

Comment: What about removing Python path in the system? [editing environment variables in Windows 10](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Comment: Hi - I removed the Python path from my user (as opposed to the system) that does solve it, but then (obviously) I can't get python when I'm not in a virtual environment ... do you know how I can do both (which I was able to do before the change I referred to above) ?

Comment: Hi, I uninstalled Python and the virtualenvwrapper-win and reinstalled; problem seems to be fixed. Thanks for helping out.